# Scanning Hebrew text

Tags: ocr, i18n

What [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) programs and resources are available to scan Hebrew/Yiddish text?

One program per answer please, and please include the following:

- Price
- Link to download or purchase site
- Does it work with Hebrew and English text on the same page?
- Can it handle [trop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trop) and [vowel signs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_vowels)?
- How accurate is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/) has OCR functionality in a number of languages. It's free, but it won't do more than a ten page document.

While you can't do two languages at once you can upload a multilingual document twice, scanning it in each language in turn and then try piece it back together again. I downloaded each scanned document in Word format and used Word to view them side by side with simultaneous scrolling.

Answer (score 3):

I think [ABBYY FineReader](http://www.abbyy.com/document_conversion/) is the leading product in this category, though I don't know more details about it. There are also other programs, such as Ligature and readIRIS. There's some free programs too such as [qhocr](http://code.google.com/p/qhocr/). You can check the details of these programs and try their free downloads. Otherwise, I would assume Bar-Ilan, HebrewBooks and Otzar haChochma would know more about this.